# How to compare two different table values with string contatct in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have two different file shows in below table, one is bugtracker and another is bugtracker (2)

[image]

Now I want to compare two statuses.

If the status is different, then count it

[image]

Comment: Can you provide sample data of the two files and an example of your desired results (i.e. what numbers are you expecting in the "Difference Count" column in your table)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're really asking for is a True or False comparison as to whether the 'Assigned User Name' and 'Status' of one table's record equals the 'Assigned User Name' and 'Status' of the other table's *matching record*, then using DAX's `if` should work.

**Assuming you've already matched and merged your "BugTracker" and "BugTracker (2)" table's records** in order to get the table you have shown above, and the merged table's name is "BugTrackerMerged", you could just add a column with this DAX command:

```
Column = if(BugTrackerMerged[Status]=BugTrackerMerged[Status2],TRUE(),FALSE())
```

*Note that I named the second status column 'Status2', instead of 'Status'. Both status columns cannot have the same name.*

**If you haven't already merged the table's records**, you'll need to do that first. I find it easiest to do that with Power Query (Power BI's Edit Queries feature).

*(I apologize up front if the following is too detailed. Not knowing your level of Power Query expertise, I figured I'd simplify discussion via step-by-step tutorial. It's more straightforward than it "looks".)*

In order to merge the two tables ("BugTracker" and "BugTracker (2)"), you'll need a common keyfield for matching and merging. *For this situation, I assume your first record in "BugTracker" should match and merge with the first record of "BugTracker (2)", your second record in "BugTracker" should match and merge with the second record of "BugTracker (2)", and so on.* Therefore, just add an index to each table.

For BugTracker, in Power Query select the "BugTracker" query:

[image]

Then click the "Add Column" tab, and then "Index Column". (That will add the index to the "BugTracker" table.)

[image]

Do the same for "BugTracker (2)".

With common indexes for both "BugTracker" and "BugTracker (2)" you can match and merge the two tables. Click the "Home" tab, then the drop-down arrow beside "Merge Queries", then "Merge Queries as New".

[image]

In the window that pops up, make the selections necessary so it looks like this and click "OK":

[image]

This creates a new query, likely called "Merge". At this point, I renamed that query to "BugTrackerMerged".

If you select that new query (now named "BugTrackerMerged") and click on "Source", under "Applied Steps"...

[image]

You'll see this code in the formula bar:

```
= Table.NestedJoin(BugTracker,{"Index"},#"BugTracker (2)",{"Index"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.FullOuter)
```

In that code, change `"NewColumn"` to `"BugTracker (2)"` to rename the column that is generated. (You could rename it as a separate step if your prefer, but I thought this approach was "cleaner".

Then click the [image] button, to the right of the "BugTracker (2)" column's title...

[image]

...to expand the tables in the column. You'll see a pop-up window like this:

[image]

Leaving the settings like shown here will expand (bring in) all the columns from the secondary table of the earlier merge. (That secondary table was "BugTracker (2)".) *Using the original column name as prefix will help you keep straight which "Status" and "Assigned User Name" info comes from which table.*

At this point, you have the merged info. You could go one step further here and do the True/False comparison here too as well, if you like. To do that, just add a new custom column with some code: click the "Add Column" tab, and the "Custom Column" button:

[image]

Then, in the pop-up window, add this code:

```
if [Status]&[Assigned User Name]=[#"BugTracker (2).Status"]&[#"BugTracker (2).Assigned User Name"] then "True" else "False"
```

Like this:

[image]

You'll get a table like this:

[image]

Your data has a lot of "Trues" up front. You can easily see that there are also "Falses" though, by using the column's filter button.

Here's my Power Query (M) code for my three queries:

BugTracker:

```
let
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\MARC_000\Desktop\sample\Rowdata Programming 15 July 2017 (2).xlsx"), null, true),
BugTracker_Sheet = Source{[Item="BugTracker",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(BugTracker_Sheet,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Index", 0, 1)
in
#"Added Index"
```

BugTracker (2):

```
let
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\MARC_000\Desktop\sample\Rowdata Programming 18 July 2017.xlsx"), null, true),
BugTracker_Sheet = Source{[Item="BugTracker",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(BugTracker_Sheet,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Changed Type", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Promoted Headers", "Index", 0, 1)
in
#"Added Index"
```

BugTrackerMerged:

```
let
Source = Table.NestedJoin(BugTracker,{"Index"},#"BugTracker (2)",{"Index"},"BugTracker (2)",JoinKind.FullOuter),
#"Expanded BugTracker (2)" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "BugTracker (2)", {"Status", "Assigned User Name", "Index"}, {"BugTracker (2).Status", "BugTracker (2).Assigned User Name", "BugTracker (2).Index"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded BugTracker (2)", "Custom", each if [Status]&[Assigned User Name]=[#"BugTracker (2).Status"]&[#"BugTracker (2).Assigned User Name"] then "True" else "False")
in
#"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Thanks @Marc for explaining with steps